# ¿Modularizar un programa que contiene una clase?

Tags: c++

El caso es que tengo que realizar un programa. Este contiene 2 funciones simples y una class GeneradorAleatorioEnteros.
El problema es que tengo que dividir el .cpp del programa en un .cpp para el main, y otro para las funciones y la clase, a demás del .h correspondiente.

De no ser porque la class es utilizada por una de las funciones podría incluirla en el mismo main... 
¿¿Como divido el programa??, Dejo el código:

```
/// La función leerá el número usando
/// una cadena, comprobará que todos los caracteres son dígitos y la 
/// convertirá a un entero. 
/// Si  es correcto, lo devolverá; si no lo es, volverá a pedirlo.
/// 
/// Otra función se encarga de pedir un rango y da un número en dicho rango.
/// 
/// Este programa incluye una class "GeneradorAleatorioEnteros".
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <random>  
#include <chrono>  

using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class GeneradorAleatorioEnteros
{  
private:

   mt19937 generador_mersenne;    // Mersenne twister
   uniform_int_distribution<int>  distribucion_uniforme;

   /************************************************************************/
   long long Nanosec(){
      return (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().
              time_since_epoch().count());
   }
   /************************************************************************/ 

public:

   /************************************************************************/   
   GeneradorAleatorioEnteros()
      :GeneradorAleatorioEnteros(0, 1){
   }

   /************************************************************************/  
   GeneradorAleatorioEnteros(int min, int max) {
      const int A_DESCARTAR = 70000;
      // ACM TOMS Volume 32 Issue 1, March 2006

      auto semilla = Nanosec();
      generador_mersenne.seed(semilla);
      generador_mersenne.discard(A_DESCARTAR);
      distribucion_uniforme = uniform_int_distribution<int> (min, max);
   }

   /************************************************************************/
   int Siguiente(){
      return (distribucion_uniforme(generador_mersenne));
   }
   /************************************************************************/
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Funcion que acepta solamente una cadena clásica de dígitos.

int leeEntero(char * cadena){

    bool Esdigito = true;   
    char * p = cadena;


    //  Bucle en el que avanzo valores mientras sean dígitos.

    while ( *p && Esdigito) { 

        if (isdigit (*p)){  
            p++;
        }

        else{
            Esdigito = false;
        }
    }

    int i = atoi(cadena);

    if (Esdigito)
        return (i);

    else{
        return (0);
    }
}

//Funcion con un dato predeterminado que acepta 1 o 2 argumentos y genera un
//número aleatorio comprendido entre los límites del intervalo aportado.
int leeEntero(int limite_superior, int limite_inferior = 0){

    GeneradorAleatorioEnteros generador_aleatorio(limite_inferior, limite_superior);
    return generador_aleatorio.Siguiente();

}

int main (){

    const int TOPE = 100;
    char cadena[TOPE];
    int * p_enteros;
    int rango_inferior, rango_superior; 
    int entero_comprendido;

    cout << "\tInserte una cadena de digitos: "<< endl;
    cin.getline (cadena, TOPE);


//Pedimos una cadena mientras contenga elementos que no sean dígitos.
    while (leeEntero(cadena) == 0){

        cout << "\tNo ha insertado digitos." << endl;
        cin.getline (cadena, TOPE);

    }

        cout << "\t" << leeEntero(cadena) << endl;

    cout << "\tInserte un rango para recibir un numero ";
    cout << "en el mismo ('0' si no inserta minimo):  " << endl;

    cin >> rango_inferior;
    cin >> rango_superior;

    if (rango_inferior == 0)    
        entero_comprendido = leeEntero(rango_superior);

    else
        entero_comprendido = leeEntero(rango_superior, rango_inferior);

    cout << "\t" << entero_comprendido << endl;



}
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo... Has sido capaz de escribir todo ese código pero no sabes dividirlo en ficheros independientes?? Me cuesta creerlo... no será más bien que has copiado el código de otro sitio o que el ejercicio es, directamente, separar el programa?

Comment: El Generador se parece pero que mucho mucho mucho al del pdf que se puede encontrar en el siguiente [enlace](https://dlscrib.com/queue/ejercicios-programacion_59e0b7f808bbc5e94de6551d_pdf?queue_id=59e0b81508bbc5ea5ce6550d) (página 16 para más inri)

Comment: Sí, suena a ejercicio de prácticas copy-pasteado con unos cuantos cambios de variables (vía traducción). Mírate esto: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include

Comment: A ver, creo que no me he explicado. Lo único que no es mio es la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un proyecto, vas añadiendo los archivos que necesites ( 3 entiendo, el de la clase lo guardas como .h, los otros dos como .cpp, uno para el main i otro para las funciones). En la cabecera del .h la defines así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al final pones #endif

Luego en los .cpp que vayas a usar la clase le pasas este .h de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya estaría, lo único que te queda por hacer es el main que si vas a usar la clase del .h tienes que volver a llamarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como en el .cpp de las funciones. Este programa no es el que has pasado pero esto siempre es igual. Es raro que sepas hacer clases y no programar en varios archivos xD.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, pásate por el [tour], [ask] y [answer] para entender cómo funciona este portal. En resumidas cuentas... una respuesta basada en imágenes no es bien recibida ya que si las mismas dejan de estar disponibles en el futuro la respuesta no valdrá absolutamente nada. Las imágenes deben ser un mero complemento de la respuesta en vez de un parte crucial

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. He conseguido modularizarlo.

Answer (score 0):

En la modularizarían, lo puedes dejar como si fuera el resultado de un mapeo de archivos donde puedes usar varios estilos, recomiendo cada función cada método y cada clase en la medida de los posible, aunque en el main se vea  más info, se puede crear asíncronas de ficheros cuando decidas.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).